# ElasticSearch aggregate by decade

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have documents and all ones contain a date field type.

What I need to achieve is to make a search and also get an aggregation of those documents based on decades.

For instance, four documents with dates:

- 2014.05.12
- 2011.03.28
- 2005.04.05
- 2003.03.02

I'd like to get an aggregation like the following one:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "release_date" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key_as_string" : "2000-2009",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key_as_string" : "2010-2020",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }]
    }
}
```

I already tried Date Histogram but it just doesn't work.

```
.addAggregation(new DateHistogramBuilder("release_date").field("release_date").interval(new DateHistogram.Interval("10y")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're really dates, how about a [date aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html)?

If they're really strings, how about a [range aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html)?

Comment: Date aggregation only allows year or century, not decade :(